# Unable to verify ownership of property/website In Google Webmaster Tools / Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, meta-tags, cname, site-verification

Google Search Console will not see a website I manage as my property.

So far I have:
- Added a TXT Record
- Added a CNAME Record
- Added META tag

And all have failed to verify. Here is where it gets funky.

The CMS we use is force.com and does not allow FTP access and therefore I am unable to upload the verification file. While I can't see if the TXT and CNAME records I can see the META tag when I inspect the code. The code is original layout like this from Google:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="secret" />
```

However when inspecting I see this, which I think is the caused by the CMS:

```
<meta content="secret" name="google-site-verification" />
```

Google may be looking for a direct match for the required code and as I can't stop the CMS from altering the code I can't proved that.

I stuck and I don't know what to do next. Any suggestions?

More Details:
DNS Records (CNAME):

[image]

Search Console Error and CNAME settings:

[image]

CNAME SCAN FAIL:

[image]

Embedded META code in the header - code seen by looking at the source code after site loads:

[image]

Comment: "I can't see if the TXT and CNAME records" - You should be able to check the DNS records? You might have to wait a while for the DNS to propagate?

Comment: Sure, and I have waited however using http://mxtoolbox.com I was unable to get the changes to show. See the images I have just added

Answer (score 1):

It isn't hard to see if your DNS TXT records are set up correctly and have propagated yet (it may take a few days).

You can use the command line tool dig to see your DNS text records and see if they include the Google verification:

```
$ dig +short -t TXT jelqtools.com
"google-site-verification=9lhJSkzu2UDWGrzgTSfk2q8m-sLN8cp5fk0atqV6XOI"
```

There are also online tools such as [this one](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx#) that have a DNS TXT lookup feature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but tried the tool you suggested and the CNAME has been added for over 48 hours and it still did not notice it. See the new images I've added

Comment: If webmaster use meta tags, then make sure they use actual address like blog.blogspot.com or www.example.com, it won't work many times if webmaster just specify example.com.